# Streamreader with custom LineBreak - Performance optimisation

Tags: c#, streamreader

## Edit: See my Solution below...

I had the following Problem to solve:
We receive Files (mostly adress-Information) from different sources, these can be in Windows Standard with CR/LF ('\r''\n') as Line Break or UNIX with LF ('\n').

When reading text in using the StreamReader.ReadLine() method, this is no Problem because it handles both cases equally.

The Problem occurs when you have a CR or a LF somewhere in the File that is not supposed to be there.
This happens for example if you Export a EXCEL-File with Cells that contain LineBreaks within the Cell to .CSV or other Flat-Files.

Now you have a File that for example has the following structure:

```
FirstName;LastName;Street;HouseNumber;PostalCode;City;Country'\r''\n'
Jane;Doe;co James Doe'\n'TestStreet;5;TestCity;TestCountry'\r''\n'
John;Hancock;Teststreet;1;4586;TestCity;TestCounty'\r''\n'
```

Now the StreamReader.ReadLine() Method reads the First Line as:

```
FirstName;LastName;Street;HouseNumber;PostalCode;City;Country
```

Which is fine but the seccond Line will be:

```
Jane;Doe;co James Doe
```

This will either break your Code or you will have false Results, as the following Line will be:

```
TestStreet;5;TestCity;TestCountry
```

So we usualy ran the File trough a tool that checks if there are loose '\n' or '\r' arround and delete them.

But this step is easy to Forget and so I tried to implement a ReadLine() method of my own. The requirement was that it would be able to use one or two LineBreak characters and those characters could be defined freely by the consuming logic.

This is the Class that I came up with:

```
 public class ReadFile
{
    private FileStream file;
    private StreamReader reader;

    private string fileLocation;
    private Encoding fileEncoding;
    private char lineBreak1;
    private char lineBreak2;
    private bool useSeccondLineBreak;

    private bool streamCreated = false;

    private bool endOfStream;

    public bool EndOfStream
    {
        get { return endOfStream; }
        set { endOfStream = value; }
    }

    public ReadFile(string FileLocation, Encoding FileEncoding, char LineBreak1, char LineBreak2, bool UseSeccondLineBreak)
    {
        fileLocation = FileLocation;
        fileEncoding = FileEncoding;
        lineBreak1 = LineBreak1;
        lineBreak2 = LineBreak2;
        useSeccondLineBreak = UseSeccondLineBreak;
    }

    public string ReadLine()
    {
        if (streamCreated == false)
        {
            file = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            reader = new StreamReader(file, fileEncoding);

            streamCreated = true;
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char[] buffer = new char[1];
        char lastChar = new char();
        char currentChar = new char();

        bool first = true;
        while (reader.EndOfStream != true)
        {
            if (useSeccondLineBreak == true)
            {
                reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
                lastChar = currentChar;

                if (currentChar == lineBreak1 && buffer[0] == lineBreak2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = buffer[0];
                }

                if (first == false)
                {
                    builder.Append(lastChar);
                }
                else
                {
                    first = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1);

                if (buffer[0] == lineBreak1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = buffer[0];
                }

                builder.Append(currentChar);
            }
        }

        if (reader.EndOfStream == true)
        {
            EndOfStream = true;
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (streamCreated == true)
        {
            reader.Close();
            file.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, it does what it is supposed to do but compared to the original StreamReader.ReadLine() method, it is ~3 Times slower. As we work with large row-Counts the difference is not only messured but also reflected in real world Performance.
(for 700'000 Rows it takes ~ 5 Seconds to read all Lines, extract a Chunk and write it to a new File, with my method it takes ~15 Seconds on my system)

I tried different aproaches with bigger buffers but so far I wasn't able to increase Performance.

What I would be interessted in:
Any suggestions how I could improve the performance of this code to get closer to the original Performance of StreamReader.ReadLine()?

## Solution:

This now takes ~6 Seconds (compared to ~5 Sec using the Default 'StreamReader.ReadLine()' ) for 700'000 Rows to do the same things as the code above does.

Thanks Jim Mischel for pointing me in the right direction!

```
public class ReadFile
    {
        private FileStream file;
        private StreamReader reader;

        private string fileLocation;
        private Encoding fileEncoding;
        private char lineBreak1;
        private char lineBreak2;
        private bool useSeccondLineBreak;

        const int BufferSize = 8192;
        int bufferedCount;
        char[] rest = new char[BufferSize];
        int position = 0;

        char lastChar;
        bool useLastChar;

        private bool streamCreated = false;

        private bool endOfStream;

        public bool EndOfStream
        {
            get { return endOfStream; }
            set { endOfStream = value; }
        }

        public ReadFile(string FileLocation, Encoding FileEncoding, char LineBreak1, char LineBreak2, bool UseSeccondLineBreak)
        {
            fileLocation = FileLocation;
            fileEncoding = FileEncoding;
            lineBreak1 = LineBreak1;
            lineBreak2 = LineBreak2;
            useSeccondLineBreak = UseSeccondLineBreak;
        }
 
        private int readInBuffer()
        {
            return reader.Read(rest, 0, BufferSize);
        }

        public string ReadLine()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            bool lineFound = false;

            if (streamCreated == false)
            {
                file = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 8192);

                reader = new StreamReader(file, fileEncoding);

                streamCreated = true;

                bufferedCount = readInBuffer();
            }
            
            while (lineFound == false && EndOfStream != true)
            {
                if (position < bufferedCount)
                {
                    for (int i = position; i < BufferSize; i++)
                    {
                        if (useLastChar == true)
                        {
                        useLastChar = false;

                        if (rest[i] == lineBreak2)
                        {
                            count++;
                            position = i + 1;
                            lineFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            builder.Append(lastChar);
                        }
                        }

                        if (rest[i] == lineBreak1)
                        {
                            if (useSeccondLineBreak == true)
                            {
                                if (i + 1 <= BufferSize - 1)
                                {
                                    if (rest[i + 1] == lineBreak2)
                                    {
                                        position = i + 2;
                                        lineFound = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        builder.Append(rest[i]);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    useLastChar = true;
                                    lastChar = rest[i];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                position = i + 1;
                                lineFound = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            builder.Append(rest[i]);
                        }

                        position = i + 1;
                    }
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    bufferedCount = readInBuffer();
                    position = 0;
                }
            }

            if (reader.EndOfStream == true && position == bufferedCount)
            {
                EndOfStream = true;
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }


        public void Close()
        {
            if (streamCreated == true)
            {
                reader.Close();
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not the implementation I would have done. Are you set on using this structure and strictly looking for performance ideas? My first thought is there are WAY too many if/else statements to make it perform well...

Comment: Are you just dealing with Excel? If so I'd seriously consider using an excel file reader instead of this approach, then you'll be able to access data on a cell by cell basis.

Comment: No, it's not just Excel, this is just an example but we receive alot of different types of files. Alot of them are flat files with different formating (delemited, Fix-Size), exportet from a DB or Excelsheet. @Ganders: the Problem, as I explained in the post is that I have to be able to both use two break characters or just one. both cases have to be differentiatet. The rest ist to check if the characters are linebreaks or not.

Comment: Copy out the StreamReader code using a decompiler or the reference sources...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to speed this up would be to have it read more than one character at a time. For example, create a 4 kilobyte buffer, read data into that buffer, and then go character-by-character. If you copy character-by-character to a `StringBuilder`, it's pretty easy.

The code below shows how to parse out lines in a loop. You'd have to split this up so that it can maintain state between calls, but it should give you the idea.

```
const int BufferSize = 4096;
const string newline = "\r\n";

using (var strm = new StreamReader(....))
{
    int newlineIndex = 0;
    var buffer = new char[BufferSize];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int charsInBuffer = 0;
    int bufferIndex = 0;
    char lastChar = (char)-1;

    while (!(strm.EndOfStream && bufferIndex >= charsInBuffer))
    {
        if (bufferIndex > charsInBuffer)
        {
            charsInBuffer = strm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (charsInBuffer == 0)
            {
                // nothing read. Must be at end of stream.
                break;
            }
            bufferIndex = 0;
        }
        if (buffer[bufferIndex] == newline[newlineIndex])
        {
            ++newlineIndex;
            if (newlineIndex == newline.Length)
            {
                // found a line
                Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                newlineIndex = 0;
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (newlineIndex > 0)
            {
                // copy matched newline characters
                sb.Append(newline.Substring(0, newlineIndex));
                newlineIndex = 0;
            }
            sb.Append(buffer[bufferIndex]);
        }
        ++bufferIndex;
    }
    // Might be a line left, without a newline
    if (newlineIndex > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(newline.Substring(0, newlineIndex));
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

You could optimize this a bit by keeping track of the starting position so that when you find a line you create a string from `buffer[start]` to `buffer[current]`, without creating a `StringBuilder`. Instead you call the [String(char[], int32, int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx) constructor. That's a little tricky to handle when you cross a buffer boundary. Probably would want to handle crossing the buffer boundary as a special case and use a `StringBuilder` for temporary storage in that case.

I wouldn't bother with that optimization, though, until after I got this first version working.

Comment: Thanks for your example, I tried a similar aproach to yours before I posted but I think I handled the overlapping Lines between buffers not well enought so I didn't get any Performance gain from it. I'll try out your aproach to see if it performs better.

Comment: @PeterZbinden: Another optimization that might help is to pre-size the `StringBuilder`. As in `new StringBuilder(Size)`, where `Size` is a constant that's slightly larger than the length of your typical expected line length. Although now that `StringBuilder` chains allocations rather than reallocating the entire buffer, that optimization might be meaningless.

Comment: I reimplemented the buffered Solution with some of your ideas, now it works alot faster (~6 Sec vs. 15 Sec. it took before, vs 5 Sec it takes the Default ReadLine() to get the Job done). Thanks for the tips, as for the string size, I have to expect all Kind of Different sizes. I got a Little Performance increase be increasing the buffer size from 4096 to 8192.

Comment: @PeterZbinden: Glad you got it working. If this solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer (click the check mark next to my answer). We work for points, ya know . . .