# C# Streamreader - Break on {CR}{LF} only

Tags: c#, .net, text-files, streamreader, flat-file

I am trying to count the number of rows in a text file (to compare to a control file) before performing a complex SSIS insert package.

Currently I am using a StreamReader and it is breaking a line with a {LF} embedded into a new line, whereas SSIS is using {CR}{LF} (correctly), so the counts are not tallying up.

Does anyone know an alternate method of doing this where I can count the number of lines in the file based on {CR}{LF} Line breaks only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could just read the file yourself and split out however you wanted; just read the bytes and when you encounter a {CR}{LF} then just start a new line.

Comment: ^- that's how StreamReader works under the covers.  Well it splits on CR, LF, and CRLF

Comment: Maybe this helps.. fast custom stream reader that also gets rid of other line breaking problems (see post) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994130/streamreader-with-custom-linebreak-performance-optimisation

Comment: @Clint: Reading bytes is not a particularly safe thing to do unless you're sure that the file encoding is a single-byte character set. In fact, if the file is 16-bit Unicode, that CR/LF pair is encoded in 4 bytes:  0x00, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x0A. Now, if you open it as text (with a `StreamReader`) and read characters . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through the file and count number of CRLFs.

Pretty straightforward implementation:

```
public int CountLines(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
    int cur, prev = -1, lines = 0;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream, encoding, false, 4096, true))
    {
        while ((cur = sr.Read()) != -1)
        {
            if (prev == '\r' && cur == '\n')
                lines++;

            prev = cur;
        }
    }

    //Empty stream will result in 0 lines, any content would result in at least one line
    if (prev != -1)
        lines++;

    return lines;
}
```

Example usage:

```
using(var s = File.OpenRead(@"<your_file_path>"))
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} lines", CountLines(s, Encoding.Default));
```

Actually it's a find substring in string task. More generic algorithms can be used.

Comment: Hope you don't run across a Unicode file in which the last byte of one character is equal to CR, and the first byte of the next character is LF. You really should note in your answer that this solution is not guaranteed to work for any Unicode encoding.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for pointing this out. Original answer would fail on any multi-byte encoding. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension-method that reads the lines with line-seperator {Cr}{Lf} only, and not {LF}. You could do a count on it.

```
var count=  new StreamReader(@"D:\Test.txt").ReadLinesCrLf().Count()
```

But could also use it for reading files, sometimes usefull since the normal StreamReader.ReadLine breaks on both {Cr}{Lf} and {LF}. Can be used on any TextReader and works streaming (file size is not an issue).

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLinesCrLf(this TextReader reader, int bufferSize = 4096)
    {
        StringBuilder lineBuffer = null;

        //read buffer            
        char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
        int charsRead;

        var previousIsLf = false;

        while ((charsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != 0)
        {
            int bufferIndex = 0;
            int writeIdx = 0;
            do
            {
                var currentChar = buffer[bufferIndex];
                switch (currentChar)
                {
                    case '\n':
                        if (previousIsLf)
                        {
                            if (lineBuffer == null)
                            {
                                //return from current buffer writeIdx could be higher than 0 when multiple rows are in the buffer                                            
                                yield return new string(buffer, writeIdx, bufferIndex - writeIdx - 1);
                                //shift write index to next character that will be read
                                writeIdx = bufferIndex + 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Debug.Assert(writeIdx == 0, $"Write index should be 0, when linebuffer != null");
                                lineBuffer.Append(buffer, writeIdx, bufferIndex - writeIdx);
                                Debug.Assert(lineBuffer.ToString().Last() == '\r',$"Last character in linebuffer should be a carriage return now");
                                lineBuffer.Length--;
                                //shift write index to next character that will be read
                                writeIdx = bufferIndex + 1;
                                yield return lineBuffer.ToString();
                                lineBuffer = null;
                            }
                        }

                        previousIsLf = false;
                        break;
                    case '\r':
                        previousIsLf = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        previousIsLf = false;
                        break;

                }


                bufferIndex++;
            } while (bufferIndex < charsRead);
            if (writeIdx < bufferIndex)
            {
                if (lineBuffer == null) lineBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                lineBuffer.Append(buffer, writeIdx, bufferIndex - writeIdx);
            }
        }
        //return last row
        if (lineBuffer != null && lineBuffer.Length > 0) yield return lineBuffer.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

{CR}{LF} is the desired.  Can't really say which is correct.

Since ReadLine strips off the end of line you don't know

Use [StreamReader.Read Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8(v=vs.110).aspx) and look for 13 followed by 10
It return Int

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty lazy way... this will read the entire file into memory.

```
var cnt = File.ReadAllText("yourfile.txt")
              .Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
              .Length;
```

Comment: Reading the whole file in one go isnt an option due to size, but nice solution for smaller files.